# Есть ли аналог WordPress, который работает без базы данных и php?

Tags: html, css, cms

Знаю html, css и хочу сделать статический мультиязычный сайт компании, но без MySQL, php и прочего (это там не нужно). Единственное что нужно от CMS -  это поддерживаемость мультиязычности, вложенности папок, и ссылки вида: mysite.com/services/remont-kvartir  (без .html, .php на конце), как в самом окне браузера, так и при наведении мыши на ссылку внутри сайта. В идеале SEO плагин. Может есть что-то подобное?

Comment: Любой конструктор сайтов а-ля Tilda

Comment: Без .html,.php в конце, seo плагин, эти слова уже подразумевают под собой использование языка программирования и конфигурации веб сервера.

Answer (score 5):

Список файловых cms, найденных на скорую руку:

- https://getgrav.org/
- https://www.bludit.com/
- https://www.wondercms.com/
- http://picocms.org/
- https://flextype.org/en
- https://automad.org/

Comment: Я так понял это констуркторы сайтов, а у меня свои html и стили

Comment: @Alan9 нет, это полноценные cms на файлах

Comment: цитирую вопрос, "без MySQL, php"...

Comment: @lezhni как думаете, есть смысл пробовать это зная только html и css?